# Vuejs 2 how to create an event on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm having some problems with creating places in fullcalendar, I'm using vue js for this but it's the first time I'm working with vue js and fullcalendar. And my problem is that I can create events in the calendar, but the event is not created on the date I click, but on today's date. And I have the impression that I didn't do something right, since the event creation method uses javascript and not vue. So can someone help me with the right way how to create events?

```
<div class="schedule-calendar bg-light card p-5">
                <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" />
            </div>

.....
select: this.selectEventFunction,
eventSources: [
                    {
                    events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {

                        axios.get('/getEvent').then(response => {
                            successCallback(response.data.data)
                        });
                    }
                    }
                ]
```

created method

```
methods: {
        selectEventFunction: function(start,end,allDays) {
            // console.log(start);
            $('#addEventCalendar').modal('toggle');

            $('#createEvent').click(function () {
                var title = $('#title').val();
                var start = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                var end = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                // console.log(start);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/event-calendar",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        title,
                        start,
                        end
                    },
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    error:function(error)
                    {
                        console.log(error)
                    },
                });
            });
        },
    },
```

Comment: vue + jquery...interesting choice. Plus, axios in one place, and jQuery ajax in another...better for your code's consistency, readability, and maintainability, to choose one library for each type of task, and stick to it. Just my opinion, though.

Comment: Really i dont want to use as much library but  i dont know how to post event in right way using vue+axios. So i am looking for a good solution as i know this is not the right way. `selectEventFunction` i need to replace with the right choise i think

Comment: Stick to using jQuery then for all the ajax requests, if you're more familiar with it. Then you can remove axios. Or even use the native fetch() Api built into all modern browsers, it does the same job